# Managing lifetime of std::variant instances - how to store pointers to std::variant values that might need to be created in a local scope?

Tags: c++, pointers, scope, polymorphism, variant

Summary: I have a run-time polymorphic requirement but I want to use `std::variant` rather than derived classes and virtual functions. How do I handle pointers to the concrete types in a collection of variants, if the variant value would have to be a local stack variable? Who is going to own this new variant instance?

---

I'm using C++20 with gcc 12.2.

I have a small program that deals with "Circles" - a simple abstraction of a 2D circle (radius, position, etc). I have a function called `intersect` that determines whether a 2D line ("ray") intersects with the circle, and returns a `std::vector` of `Intersection` objects as a result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Circle {
    std::string name {};
    double radius {};
    double x{}, y{};
};

struct Intersection {
    double t {};
    Circle const * circle {};
};

struct Ray {
    double origin_x{}, origin_y{};
    double direction_x{}, direction_y{};
};

std::vector<Intersection> intersect(Circle const & circle, Ray const & ray) {
    // ...

    // the case where the ray crosses the circle in two places:
    double t1 = 0.1;  // dummy value for testing
    double t2 = 0.4;  // dummy value for testing

    return {{t1, &circle}, {t2, &circle}};
}

int main() {
    Circle circle {"circle", 1.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    Ray ray {-2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0};

    auto intersections = intersect(circle, ray);

    for (auto & i : intersections) {
        std::cout << i.t << " : " << i.circle->name << '\n';
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/9GfPa9z1v

Note that the `Intersection::circle` data member is a *pointer* to a `Circle` instance, because I do not want to create an entire copy of a `Circle` for each intersection. This is because of memory and performance considerations.

Now I wish to add a run-time variation to the shape, so that this code can handle, say, `Square` as well as `Circle`.

I could do this with inheritance and virtual functions, but for learning purposes I'm exploring the use of `std::variant` instead, leading to the following (which does not compile for reasons I'll explain shortly, as it is the crux of my question):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <variant>

struct Circle {
    std::string name {};
    double radius {};
    double x{}, y{};
};

struct Square {
    std::string name {};
    double side_len {};
    double x{}, y{};
};

using Shape = std::variant<Circle, Square>;

struct Intersection {
    double t {};
    Shape const * shape {};
};

struct Ray {
    double origin_x{}, origin_y{};
    double direction_x{}, direction_y{};
};

std::vector<Intersection> intersect(Circle const & circle, Ray const & ray) {
    // ...

    // the case where the ray crosses the circle in two places:
    double t1 = 0.1;  // dummy value for testing
    double t2 = 0.4;  // dummy value for testing

    return {{t1, &circle}, {t2, &circle}};  // <---- COMPILE ERROR
}

std::vector<Intersection> intersect(Square const & square, Ray const & ray) {
    // ...

    double t1 = 0.2;  // dummy value for testing
    double t2 = 0.8;  // dummy value for testing
    
    return {{t1, &square}, {t2, &square}};  // <---- COMPILE ERROR
}

int main() {
    Circle circle {"circle", 1.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    Square square {"square", 1.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    
    std::vector<Shape> shapes {};
    shapes.push_back(circle);
    shapes.push_back(square);
    
    Ray ray {-2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0};

    auto name_visitor = [](auto const & shape) { return shape.name; };
    auto intersect_visitor = [ray](auto const & shape) { return intersect(shape, ray); };

    for (auto & shape : shapes) {
        std::cout << std::visit(name_visitor, shape) << '\n';
        auto intersections = std::visit(intersect_visitor, shape);

        for (auto & i : intersections) {
            std::cout << i.t << " : " << i.shape->name << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/d4qEWb8bn

The compiler errors are of this type:

```
<source>:36:41: error: could not convert '{{t1, (& circle)}, {t2, (& circle)}}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::vector<Intersection>'
   36 |     return {{t1, &circle}, {t2, &circle}};
      |                                         ^
      |                                         |
      |                                         <brace-enclosed initializer list>
```

And **I expect this**, because the variable I'm taking the address of (`circle` in this function, `square` in the other) is not of variant type `Shape`, thus the address of this variable is not suitable as a `Shape *` in the `Intersection`'s initialisation.

My question is, how would I modify this code to support using `std::variant` when I want to preserve the use of pointers rather than value copies?

For example, I can't create a `std::variant(circle)` and use a pointer to that, because that would be a pointer to a local variable that would immediately go out of scope. I've also read that the Standard does not provide any guarantee that a pointer to a `std::variant` is a valid pointer to one of its types, so a simple cast would not work either.

One idea I had was to create a separate variant type for pointers to shapes, `ShapePtr`, and modify `Intersection` to store values of this type, which simply wrap a pointer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <variant>

struct Circle {
    std::string name {};
    double radius {};
    double x{}, y{};
};

struct Square {
    std::string name {};
    double side_len {};
    double x{}, y{};
};

using Shape = std::variant<Circle, Square>;
using ShapePtr = std::variant<Circle const *, Square const *>;

struct Intersection {
    double t {};
    ShapePtr shape {};
};

struct Ray {
    double origin_x{}, origin_y{};
    double direction_x{}, direction_y{};
};

std::vector<Intersection> intersect(Circle const & circle, Ray const & ray) {
    // ...

    // the case where the ray crosses the circle in two places:
    double t1 = 0.1;  // dummy value for testing
    double t2 = 0.4;  // dummy value for testing

    return {{t1, ShapePtr{&circle}}, {t2, ShapePtr{&circle}}};
}

std::vector<Intersection> intersect(Square const & square, Ray const & ray) {
    // ...

    double t1 = 0.2;  // dummy value for testing
    double t2 = 0.8;  // dummy value for testing
    
    return {{t1, &square}, {t2, &square}};
}

int main() {
    Circle circle {"circle", 1.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    Square square {"square", 1.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    
    std::vector<Shape> shapes {};
    shapes.push_back(circle);
    shapes.push_back(square);
    
    Ray ray {-2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0};

    auto name_visitor = [](auto const & shapeptr) { return shapeptr->name; };
    auto intersect_visitor = [ray](auto const & shape) { return intersect(shape, ray); };

    for (auto & shape : shapes) {
        auto intersections = std::visit(intersect_visitor, shape);

        for (auto & i : intersections) {
            std::cout << i.t << " : " << std::visit(name_visitor, i.shape) << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rnjbT9rbf

This compiles, and works, but it requires two variant types that need to be maintained - `Shape` and `ShapePtr`, and it also has implications for mixing `const` and non-`const` pointers. This example only uses `const` pointers, so it is relatively simple, but once non-`const` pointers are needed, it may get very complicated.

I've also considered changing the interfaces of `intersect(Circle...` and `intersect(Square...` to both take `Shape` instead, and renaming them, and then using logic in the visitor to make sure the correct function is called depending on the concrete type, and then resolve this to the concrete type at the start of the function, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <variant>

struct Circle {
    std::string name {};
    double radius {};
    double x{}, y{};
};

struct Square {
    std::string name {};
    double side_len {};
    double x{}, y{};
};

using Shape = std::variant<Circle, Square>;

struct Intersection {
    double t {};
    Shape const * shape {};
};

struct Ray {
    double origin_x{}, origin_y{};
    double direction_x{}, direction_y{};
};

std::vector<Intersection> intersect_circle(Shape const & shape, Ray const & ray) {
    Circle const * circle = std::get_if<Circle>(&shape);

    // ...

    // the case where the ray crosses the circle in two places:
    double t1 = 0.1;  // dummy value for testing
    double t2 = 0.4;  // dummy value for testing

    return {{t1, &shape}, {t2, &shape}};
}

std::vector<Intersection> intersect_square(Shape const & shape, Ray const & ray) {
    Square const * square = std::get_if<Square>(&shape);
    
    // ...

    double t1 = 0.2;  // dummy value for testing
    double t2 = 0.8;  // dummy value for testing
    
    return {{t1, &shape}, {t2, &shape}};
}

std::vector<Intersection> intersect(Shape const & shape, Ray const & ray) {
    if (std::holds_alternative<Circle>(shape)) {
        return intersect_circle(shape, ray);
    } else if (std::holds_alternative<Square>(shape)) {
        return intersect_square(shape, ray);
    }
    return {};
}

int main() {
    Circle circle {"circle", 1.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    Square square {"square", 1.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    
    std::vector<Shape> shapes {};
    shapes.push_back(circle);
    shapes.push_back(square);
    
    Ray ray {-2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0};

    auto name_visitor = [](auto const & shape) { return shape.name; };
    auto intersect_visitor = [ray](auto & shape) { return intersect(shape, ray); };

    for (auto & shape : shapes) {
        auto intersections = std::visit(intersect_visitor, shape);

        for (auto & i : intersections) {
            std::cout << i.t << " " << std::visit(name_visitor, *i.shape) << '\n';  // LINE 78
        }
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ozns1Kfo7

Unfortunately this crashes with `std::bad_alloc` when trying to dereference `i.shape` on line 78 - haven't worked that one out yet... but assuming I can fix that, then this seems plausible. I avoid a second `std::variant` type, but I do need to maintain the dispatching function. This seems workable - but is it idiomatic?

Therefore I seek your advice on what may be the best approach for mixing pointers with `std::variant` in C++20, and if there may be more idiomatic ways to handle this kind of problem, especially if I'm going about it poorly.

---

Aside: I struggled a bit with the Title of this question - it's difficult for me to fully explain what I'm trying to do in a single sentence. If anyone can suggest an edit to the Title, I'd be happy to consider changing it. Apologies if anyone was thrown off by it.

Comment: Did you try using unique_ptr or a shared_ptr to the variants? Ownership problems solved!

Comment: I haven't considered that - that could be a good way to handle the lifetime. I will think about that some more.

Comment: I would like to avoid dynamic allocation within `intersect()` though, which does mean that I really need to retain a pointer to something that is passed in.

Comment: The shown code is TLDR. My comment reflects the most common way to manage object lifetimes that cannot be easily implemented in automatic scope.

Answer (score 0):

I considered using smart pointers but that results in heap allocation, which I want to avoid in this case as it makes my program about 10x slower.

Thinking more about it, I realised that the `Intersection` type could be generic based on the type of the object passed in, thus it would just retain a pointer to whatever type was provided.

I could have removed the storage of the pointer entirely, changing the vector returned by `intersect()` to be just `t`, and added it in the caller by creating a new vector combining pairs of `t` and the object pointer. However this would result in allocation of a second vector, which is almost certainly slower than building the original vector completely in the first instance.

Another requirement that became clearer as I experimented is that I wanted the `intersect()` function to work on the non-variant concrete types as well, so I needed to provide overloads for this.

And lastly, I wanted to provide "member function" call syntax for the erased type, such that I could call `shape.get_name()` for example. This makes the `Shape` type look more like the concrete types to the user.

This resulted in:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <variant>

struct Circle {
    std::string name {};
    double radius {};
    double x{}, y{};

    auto get_name() const { return name; }
};

struct Square {
    std::string name {};
    double side {};
    double x{}, y{};

    auto get_name() const { return name; }
};

struct Shape {
    std::variant<Circle, Square> variant;

    auto get_name() const {
        auto name_visitor = [](auto const & variant) { return variant.name; };
        return std::visit(name_visitor, variant);
    }

};

template <typename Object>
struct Intersection {
    double t {};
    Object const * object {};
};

struct Ray {
    double origin_x{}, origin_y{};
    double direction_x{}, direction_y{};
};

Circle const * get_circle_ptr(Circle const & circle) { return &circle; }
Circle const * get_circle_ptr(Shape const & shape) { return std::get_if<Circle>(&shape.variant); }

Square const * get_square_ptr(Square const & square) { return &square; }
Square const * get_square_ptr(Shape const & shape) { return std::get_if<Square>(&shape.variant); }

template <typename Object>
std::vector<Intersection<Object>> intersect_circle(Object const & object, Ray const & ray) {
    auto circle = get_circle_ptr(object);
    // ...

    // the case where the ray crosses the circle in two places:
    double t1 = circle->radius * 0.1;  // dummy value for testing
    double t2 = circle->radius * 0.4;  // dummy value for testing

    return {{t1, &object}, {t2, &object}};
}

template <typename Object>
std::vector<Intersection<Object>> intersect_square(Object const & object, Ray const & ray) {
    auto square = get_square_ptr(object);

    // ...

    // the case where the ray crosses the square in two places:
    double t1 = square->side * 0.2;  // dummy value for testing
    double t2 = square->side * 0.8;  // dummy value for testing
    
    return {{t1, &object}, {t2, &object}};
}

// `intersect` wrappers for concrete classes
std::vector<Intersection<Circle>> intersect(Circle const & circle, Ray const & ray) {
    return intersect_circle(circle, ray);
}

std::vector<Intersection<Square>> intersect(Square const & square, Ray const & ray) {
    return intersect_square(square, ray);
}

std::vector<Intersection<Shape>> intersect(Shape const & shape, Ray const & ray) {
    if (std::holds_alternative<Circle>(shape.variant)) {
        return intersect_circle(shape, ray);
    } else if (std::holds_alternative<Square>(shape.variant)) {
        return intersect_square(shape, ray);
    }
    return {};
}

int main() {
    Circle circle {"circle", 1.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    Square square {"square", 1.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    
    std::vector<Shape> shapes {};
    shapes.push_back(Shape {circle});
    shapes.push_back(Shape {square});
    
    Ray ray {-2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0};

    // intersect on the Shape type
    for (auto & shape : shapes) {
        auto intersections = intersect(shape, ray);

        for (auto & i : intersections) {
            std::cout << i.t << " " << i.object->get_name() << '\n';
        }
    }

    // intersect on the concrete type
    auto circle_intersections = intersect(circle, ray);
    for (auto & i : circle_intersections) {
        std::cout << i.t << " " << i.object->get_name() << '\n';
    }

    auto square_intersections = intersect(square, ray);
    for (auto & i : square_intersections) {
        std::cout << i.t << " " << i.object->get_name() << '\n';
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/q9Wo1GzfP

The key points are:

1. The "Shape" type is now a `struct` containing the `std::variant<Circle, Square>` as a data member. It also provides a `get_name()` member function to demonstrate retrieval of the concrete type's data.
2. The `Intersection` struct is now templated on the `Object` type, which I intend to be one of either `Circle`, `Square`, or `Shape`. Thus the pointer type in the returned vector of intersections is dependent on how the `intersect()` function is called. If I pass a pre-constructed `Shape` (a wrapped variant), then I get pointers to the `Shape` instance back. If I pass in instances of a concrete type like `Circle`, then I get pointers to those back. As long as my code doesn't need to combine these intersection vectors, the function works to get the results I need.
3. The functions that do the work are renamed `intersect_circle` and `intersect_square`, and they are templated on the object type. There is an assumption that these are called appropriately by the invoked `intersect()` overload. These obtain a pointer to the concrete type contained within the variant, and perform the correct calculations, but most importantly, the pointer stored in the intersections vector is a pointer to the instance of either the concrete type, or the `Shape` type, if it was passed when called.

This is quite a lot of indirection just to implement this kind of polymorphism, however it does seem to work in my case, and as far as I can tell does not involve any heap allocation other than the `std::vector`, as `std::variant` is not allowed to use any heap memory when allocating their value.

All that said, perhaps there's an even better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass a pointer to the `Shape` object through to the `intersect` function:

```
std::vector<Intersection> intersect(Shape const * shape, Circle const & circle, Ray const & ray) {
    // ...

    // the case where the ray crosses the circle in two places:
    double t1 = 0.1;  // dummy value for testing
    double t2 = 0.4;  // dummy value for testing

    return {{t1, shape}, {t2, shape}};
}

std::vector<Intersection> intersect(Shape const * shape, Square const & square, Ray const & ray) {
    // ...

    double t1 = 0.2;  // dummy value for testing
    double t2 = 0.8;  // dummy value for testing
    
    return {{t1, shape}, {t2, shape}};
}

// ...

for (auto & shape : shapes) {
    auto intersect_visitor = [ray, shape](auto const & alternative) {
        return intersect(&shape, alternative, ray);
    };
    auto intersections = std::visit(intersect_visitor, shape);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's nice and simple, Btw, should it be `return intersect(&shape, alternative, ray);`?

Comment: @davidA yes, fixed now